# What replaces nav lists in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am preparing to update my site to Bootstrap 3, but I can’t figure out how to replace [the `nav-list` class from Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs).

I looked into [list groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group), but I am not sure if this is to be used to replace nav lists. How would I make the below markup work in Bootstrap 3?

```html
<div class="well">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

This is the look I am going for: http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/2Nguy/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### EDIT

The removal of `.nav-list` [has been documented](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10419) in [Migrating to v3.x – What’s removed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/migration/#dropped):

> Nav lists
>   `.nav-list` `.nav-header`
>   No direct equivalent, but [list groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#list-group) and [`.panel-group`s](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse) are similar.

---

I found this change listed in the changelog inside the [“WIP: Bootstrap 3” pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342):

> - **Remove `.nav-list` option**. Replaced by the new `.list-group` component.

So if I translate your code to use `.list-group` instead, I get this:

```html
<div class="well">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="well">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, this does not look identical to the way it did in Bootstrap 2. As I [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281636/what-replaces-nav-lists-in-bootstrap-3/18281984#comment26819666_18281984) in this answer’s comments, there seems to be no exact `.nav-list` equivalent built-in to Bootstrap 3. So if you need features that `.list-group` doesn’t have, you will have to write the CSS yourself, or try to port it from Bootstrap 2.

Comment: I guess I will have to use some custom css to get the exact look I am going for. Thanks for the link to the pull request!

Comment: @BlakePlumb Looking at the “list groups” section of the Bootstrap 3 docs, I don’t see any way to mimic the old styles. And there’s a GitHub Issue “[There is nav-list in bootstrap 3?](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9139)” that the developer answered simply “No” to. So yes, you will have to use custom CSS.

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6X6L/3/embedded/result/) of a Bootstrap 3 solution to the missing side navbar and then a large content area similar to [the 2.3.2 documentation example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html).

Answer (score 9):

I used `class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"` and for me it's a better styled replacement. But perhaps it is resolved in version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 9):

The following .less will bring back `nav-list` more or less as it was in 2.3.2:

```
@import "../bootstrap/variables.less"; // replace with path to bootstrap variables.less

// Nav headers (for dropdowns and lists)
.nav-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: @line-height-small;
  color: @gray-light;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
// Space them out when they follow another list item (link)
.nav li + .nav-header {
  margin-top: 9px;
}

// NAV LIST
// --------

.nav-list {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-list > li > a,
.nav-list .nav-header {
  margin-left:  -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.nav-list > li > a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
.nav-list > .active > a,
.nav-list > .active > a:hover,
.nav-list > .active > a:focus {
  color: @body-bg;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background-color: @link-color;
}
.nav-list [class^="icon-"],
.nav-list [class*=" icon-"] {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
// Dividers (basically an hr) within the dropdown
.nav-list .divider {
  .nav-divider();
}
```

The resulting CSS is:

```
.nav-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #999999;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav li + .nav-header {
  margin-top: 9px;
}
.nav-list {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-list > li > a,
.nav-list .nav-header {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav-list > li > a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
.nav-list > .active > a,
.nav-list > .active > a:hover,
.nav-list > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.nav-list [class^="icon-"],
.nav-list [class*=" icon-"] {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.nav-list .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Include the CSS or the LESS after the normal bootstrap asset.

Answer (score 3):

I created a gist that takes nav-list from bootstrap 2.3.2, fills in some variables that aren't available in 3.0 under the same name, and resolves a mixin dependency. It's all straight defaults, and seems (so far) to play well with updated bootstrap 3.0 wells, which is where I primarily use it.

https://gist.github.com/jimbojsb/6754116

Answer (score 0):

For me the replace was:

```
nav nav-pills
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#badges

Under the title "Adapts to active nav states"