# Active class on bootstrap list not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/6sdCb/2/

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<label class="nav-header">Payment</label>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<label class="nav-header">Personal</label>
<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was under the impression I could use the active list class to highlight the current item but when I apply this class it doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong please?

Comment: Add `.active { background: cyan; }`

Comment: `nav-list` was removed in bootstrap 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281636/what-replaces-nav-lists-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the class nav-list to nav-bar, and add a default theme class to the nav-bar class:

```
<section class="navbar navbar-default">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<!-- <ul class="nav nav-list">  REMOVE nav-list -->

<label class="nav-header">Payment</label>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<label class="nav-header">Personal</label>
<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Check this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6sdCb/4/

The active class will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's CSS class `active` only applies to certain links such as when you are styling `a` elements as a button in the following example:

> ```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">Primary button</button>
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">Button</button>
> ```

(from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-active)

For `ul.nav`s, there is an `active` CSS class style available for `nav-tabs` as show at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs but there doesn't appear to be any for `nav-list` which is what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added .active class. 
You can check the following edited css code:

```
    body {
    padding:30px;
}
.active{
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

not `nav-list`, but `nav-pills nav-stacked`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sdCb/5/)