# Bootstrap v3.3.0 - Side nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started learning Bootstrap and recreating my old site. I had my side nav done, when yesterday I noticed there is a new Bootstrap release v3.3. That version is missing some of the classes the previous boostrap.css had, such as the `nav-list' I was using (below). Is that common? Should I expect to loose classes with new Boostrap releases? 
It's not a big deal, I can create my own, of course. [Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) don't even demo a stackable side nav! Am I missing linking to some file?

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Seciton Header</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Seciton Header 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.nav-list` was part of Twitter Bootstrap 2, and we're talking of Bootstrap 3 here... This is normal that a new **version** brings major changes, as dropped functionalities, and new ones.

Have a look on [Bootstrap migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/). You'll see that:

> [.nav-list have] no direct equivalent, but list groups and .panel-groups are similar.

Here's how to get a similar behavior in Bootstrap 3:

- use `.nav-pills.nav-stacked` instead of `.nav-list`
- replace `.nav-header` by `.disabled`
- wrap you "nav-header" content in a `<a>`

**Twitter Bootstrap 2.3:**

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Seciton Header</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Seciton Header 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 3.3:**

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="disabled"><a>Seciton Header</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a>Seciton Header</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: [What replaces nav lists in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281636/what-replaces-nav-lists-in-bootstrap-3)

> The removal of .nav-list has been documented in Migrating from 2.x to 3.0

In the second answer is also mentioned how to add it back, using less or css.